# SQL Server- Duplicate rows n times for all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a db with over 150 tables which I need to artificially inflate for stress-testing. So basically I've built an app which extracts the said db, but am currently working with a snippet of what the actual db might look like. Thereby, I'm looking to inflate the db as a whole so as to stress-test my application.

I've thought to repeat the current set of rows n times to make it artificially big enough. Now the issue that is arising is because of keys. They cannot be repetitive, so I thought to augment the key with the loop counter (_i). As far as I think, this should work and be stable enough to get me through. Basically, the idea is as follows:

- *loop over the list of tables*
- *identify if the field is a key in a table, if yes, augment with loop counter*
- *insert query n times*

So, to identify the primary and foreign keys, I've written a basic SQL query:

```
select C.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C 
ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE C.TABLE_NAME =" + table + " 
and T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

This gives me a list of keys while being looped over the list of tables obtained via:

```
SELECT concat('''',TABLE_NAME,'''') AS TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'db_name'
```

Now following the psuedo-code, what's left of me to do is the INSERT query, which would actually loop over the fields, check if a key, then loop over the rows to re-insert in the said table. I am struggling with this aspect of the code and would request the community's assistance on it. I wouldn't mind corrections on my approach too. The language I'm using is either C# or Python.

I was advised that doing this in ssms would be a better idea, purely an SQL based approach, but didn't find any luck there. If you have any suggestions, please help me out.

Comment: A primary key may consist of more than one column (composite key). You also need to handle foreign keys and consider the underlying column data types in order to clone rows with new keys. A generalized approach is non-trivial.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes I understand, the query for primary key identification also works for foreign keys, so the list has both of them. Do you have any tips on the approach?

Comment: I suggest you disable foreign key constraints and reenable afterwards to avoid extra code to handle dependency order.

Comment: One of the non-trivial parts that Dan is referring to is the actual generation of the foreign keys themselves because one of the constraints of foreign keys is that the value being referenced must exist in the parent table. Since you plan to pseudo-randomly generate your primary keys, when it comes time to generate your foreign keys, you'll need to make sure you pick valid values and therefore won't be able to use the same approach as your primary key generation process. That being said, it may be a simpler process of just copying the foreign keys from existing rows of that table, or it may...

Comment: ...not be that simple depending on the other constraints defined on your tables. Your goal is accomplishable in pure SQL, probably with dynamic SQL, but I think is definitely harder of a challenge that way as opposed to using application code like C#. If I can think of a simpler approach I'll add an answer but my question is what exactly are you trying to stress test?...ideally your queries should function the same regardless of how much or how little data you have, if the selectivity (uniqueness) of that data is constant. Depending on your goal, you can stress test with small data too.

Comment: @J.D. that is actually a fair point you are mentioning about foreign keys that I hadn't considered and could actually mess up the code. Next, like I said I was advised a purely SQL approach would make more sense as confirmed by you too, so I'm thinking to actually change the approach. Lastly, what I am trying to stress test is my application. So the application is supposed to work something out and then extract the database. That extraction process is not completely SQL/queries based, hence the testing comes in. The actual data may have millions of rows in tables, while the one I currently...

Comment: ... I have contains tens of thousands. Therefore, the inflation needs be done. I would be keen on your dynamic SQL approach. I initially was trying to write a process and functions to do the same thing but had no luck.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you're not trying to stress test the database or SQL queries themselves, rather you're trying to stress test the application code and process?

Comment: @J.D. yes absolutely

Comment: Gotcha, in that case why not create the stress in the application layer instead then? What I mean is, don't worry about creating dummy data in the database, rather pull in the rows you have already into the application as the first step, then just create a new collection that is generated from those source records by iterating those source records multiple times. This way you don't need to worry about things like primary key and foreign key constraints. Then hand that new collection over to your application code you're actually trying to stress test, simulating like it came from the database.